# Why articles being ommited sometime?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

Sometime before nouns there's no definite or indefinite articles like in this sentence (before `representatives` and `congressional districts`):

> The House of Representative is composed of representatives elected from congressional districts.

Comment: When a plural noun is not required to take the definite article, it can stand alone without an article. The indefinite article "a(n)" can only be used with singular nouns. The singular "a congressional district" corresponds to the plural "congressional districts".

Comment: It's "The House of Representative***s***."  If "representative" were actually singular, meaning there were only one representative, you'd be right as it then should be "The House of the Representative."  But "representative" isn't actually singular.  You've copied the name wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plural nouns do not require articles.  A singular noun does.

There is a singular house and multiple representatives in "The House of Representatives", which is why house has an article and representatives do not.

"Congressional districts" is also plural, which is why it doesn't need an article.

Comment: "Plural nouns do not require articles" Huh?

Comment: If a noun refers to a collection of objects like "representatives", you do not need an article before it such as in "the house of representatitves".  Let's say we were talking about one particular representative's house, then you would call it "the house of the representative".  Any representative's house would be "the house of a representative".  But if you're referring to a collection of representatives, you don't have any articles before it.  Does this help?